# Not able to get the answer with the help of synchronized method in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have to read the content from the file F1 and F2 and move it to new file (f3) using Multi-threading in Java. The problem I am facing is that when I am using synchronized in method I am not able to get the answer, but when I am not synchronizing the method I was able to get the answer.

Below is the code with synchronized method which is only printing the content of one file:

```
package com.company;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class FileMerge{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WriteToFile pc = new WriteToFile();
        //Create a Thread1 to read the content of file 1
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                   try {
                    pc.file1();
                } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);

                }
            }
        });

        // Create  Thread 2 to read the content of file 2
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    pc.file2();
                } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);

                }
            }
        });


        //Start the Thread
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }

    public static class WriteToFile{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/paras.jain/Desktop/des.txt");

        public WriteToFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        }


        public synchronized void file1() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
            // BufferedReader object for file1.txt
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\paras.jain\\Desktop\\f.txt"));
            String line = br.readLine();
            //System.out.println("----------" + line);

            // loop to copy each line of
            // file1.txt to file3.txt
            while (line != null) {
                pw.println(line);

                line = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
            pw.close();

        }

        public  synchronized void file2() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/paras.jain/Desktop/f2.txt"));
            String line2 = br1.readLine();
            //System.out.println("----------" + line2);


            // loop to copy each line of
            // file2.txt to file3.txt
            while (line2 != null) {
                pw.println(line2);
                line2 = br1.readLine();
                //System.out.println("----------" + line2);
            }
            br1.close();
            pw.close();

        }
    }
}
```

Output of the above code is :

```
File 1 line 1 
File 1 line 2
File 1 line 3
```

When I run the code **WITHOUT synchronize** method I got the following output:

```
File 1 line 1
File 1 line 2
File 2 line 1
File 2 line 2
File 1 line 3
File 2 line 3
```

Why is that difference in the output? And how I can I get the second output with the help of Synchronized method?

Comment: You cannot / should not write to a file from two threads at the same time. This will result in garbled/mixed text. And adding synchronized to the method definitions is doing nothing for you.

Comment: @ControlAltDel If you actually look at the code, adding synchronized to the method definitions is doing *everything*, because it ensures that one file is copied in its entirety before the other file is copied. With `synchronized` where OP has put them, there is no garbled/mixed text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `file1()` and `file2()` methods are synchronized, one of them has to complete before the other can run.

Since you start the thread that runs `file1()` first, it likely wins the race, so `file1()` must complete before `file2()` can run.

Unfortunately, `file1()` **closes the PrintWriter**, so when `file2()` runs, all the `pw.println(...)` calls **fails silently**.

Why silently? Because that's the way they defined it. See javadoc of [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html):

> Methods in this class never throw I/O exceptions, although some of its constructors may. The client may inquire as to whether any errors have occurred by invoking [`checkError()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError--).

Comment: So if we sleep the thread that uses file1 then why there is no change in the answer.I mean If I use t1.sleep(1000);  then also there is no change in the answer. I will use the sleep after starting thread t2

Comment: @Parasjain `t1.sleep(1000)` actually means `Thread.sleep(1000)`, because the [`sleep(long millis)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) method is `static`, and as the javadoc says: *Causes the **currently executing thread** to sleep.* That means the `main` thread is sleeping, not thread `t1`, so it doesn't affect anything the 2 threads are doing.

Comment: What if I use **join**  to finish the thread `t1` and then thread `t2` or any other method to sleep the thread `t1`

Comment: @Parasjain What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to sleep a thread? What do you want to happen? Do you want the same mixed result that you get without synchronized? Or do you want all of one file before then other? If so, why even use multi-threading?

Comment: Thanks for the response really appreciate it ,One last question: When we are not using synchronize than both the thread are running parallely , than according to your explain one thread which will finish first will automatically close the **PrintWriter** for the second thread , Then how come both thread are running completely and printing all the line ?

Comment: @Parasjain Arbitrary. Race condition. It just so happens that `t1` prints line 3, then `t2` prints line 3, then `t1` closes, then `t2` closes (ignored). Or maybe it's `t2` that closes and `t1` closing is ignored. Or sometime one of the threads might close before the other gets to print it all. It's a race condition, and therefore unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks alot It really helped me.